# javascript code in vba

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-word

I want to write some javascript code I have in vba for word

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var l = images.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}
```

I tested this in the console in chrome and it deletes all images in html document at once

I want to open the html document in word 2010 and remove the images

I have been able to delete images using this

```
Public Sub PicturesDeleteAll()

Dim objPic As Shape

    For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            objPic.Delete
    Next objPic

End Sub
```

but it does not delete them all at once and I have to run it several times to work so what is the vba equivant of the javascript code I have?

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean you have to run `PicturesDeleteAll` several times? you are not referring to watching the loop loop several times (i.e. once per image). Do you get any error messages or are you saying that it just. doesnt pic up all images on each pass, and with out changes it randomly picks up a few more each time?

Comment: yes I have to run PicturesDeleteAll several times to delete all the images on the document. While I run the javascript code only once. Not optimal if I am doing this for many files. No error message it just takes 3 to 4 times to get all the images deleted.

Comment: There is something I'm not seeing here, Do you have any other information? It is actually more than one HTML file? is it erroring and stopping and that is why you have to run it again? What you are describing, may be possible, but is unheard of and unlikely, hence I think im missing something that is happening

Comment: No, I am running it on one HTML file open in word. No errors just stops after deleting some images in the document so I have to run it again to delete the rest like 3, 4 times. Possible might be missing this? For Inline Shapes, replace "Shape" with "InlineShape" and ".Shapes" with ".InlineShapes"?

Comment: Nope that wouldn't do it as it wouldnt 'eventually' get them all deleted like you are describing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a scenario in which this would happen however, when deleting it can be better to do it in reverse to avoid a changing array size giving misleading results that could be symptomatic of what you are seeing.

Try the below: -

```
Public Sub PicturesDeleteAll()
Dim LngCounter As Long

For Each LngCounter = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count to 0 Step -1
    ActiveDocument.Shapes(LngCounter).Delete
Next 
End Sub
```

or

```
Public Sub PicturesDeleteAll()
Do Until ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count = 0 
    ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Delete
Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: first one gave a error, second one did the job. Thanks alot! just tested it works great

Comment: Just one more thing can I adapt this to delete sections, for example if I find a section with a string "top section to delete" or "bottom section to delete" how would I do that? I know this deletes sections ActiveDocument.Sections(x).Range.Delete where x is section number

Comment: @AK0101 yes you could do that but there isn't room in comments to answer it, your best of raising a new question with as much detail as possible and  showing what code you have so far.